# Why does `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps` lint rule trigger on nested object properties?

Tags: react-hooks, eslint, usecallback, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

I'm trying to use React hooks for memoizing a callback.  This callback specifically uses a function that's defined on an object.

```js
const setValue = useCallback((value) => {
    field.setValue(key, value);
}, [field.setValue, key]);
```

This triggers Eslint rule `react-hooks/exhaustive-deps`.  
It wants me to instead pass in `[field, key]`.

If I then change the code to the following, I get no warning even though it seems equivalent:

```js
const { setValue: setFieldValue } = field;

const setValue = useCallback((value) => {
  setFieldValue(key, value);
}, [setFieldValue, key]);
```

Why is Eslint warn me in the first example?
Can I safely ignore it in such circumstances?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook/55854902#55854902)

Comment: I took a look, and it's not a duplicate.  The function in that question is not being referenced an object.

Comment: @MattHuggins wouldn't the second example throw an error :/ ? You are redeclaring the same var.

Comment: @James - thanks for pointing that out, I've updated the example to better replicate my scenario.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the linting rule to me. In your first example, `field.setValue` is certainly the better thing to pass. If react does deep object equality checking in hooks then this prevents un-necessary checks, and if they don't then passing `field` is just plain incorrect.

Comment: That was my sentiment as well.  I figured either I'm missing something, or I'm taking crazy pills. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this.

```
const setValue = useCallback((value) => {
  const set = field.setValue;
  set(key, value);
}, [field.setValue, key]);
```

But it's not recommended.Take a look at this explanation. https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15924#issuecomment-521253636

Comment: Thanks for official word from Facebook on this.  I assumed it had to do with `this` context, but couldn't find anything related to it.